# recognize return value that get of web method in ajax-jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i wrote a web method that has  string return value.this return value get form stored procedure .but when condition not be established the undefined value returned.i wrote the following code but it did not work

```
   $.ajax(
                                                {
 type: "POST",
  url: "WebForm1.aspx/confirm",
  data: JSON.stringify({
  username: username,
  password: password, email: email,codemeli: codemeli}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

       async: true,
       cache: false,
       success: function (ret) {

             if (ret != "") {
             $('#result').text(ret.d + " : " + "it is reserved  "+ret.lenght); }
          else { $('#result').text("the operation is successful"); }
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
         $('#result').text(x.responseText);
            }
            }
       );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ret.lenght` should be `ret.d.length` in your `success` callback.

Comment: i do it but it returned undefined still